# Running into a problem with MFC serialization

Tags: c++, mfc

I am running into an issue regarding serialization with MFC `CArchive` in a small project I am working on.

I got storing into the archive and then to a file working fine (I hope so) but reading from the file returns the object's properties as `NULL`.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is storing last up to 10 sales into an archive and loading back in when desired into a `CTypedPtrArray`

This is the `Serialize` function:

```
void MainStore::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    
    CObject::Serialize(ar);
    
    
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {   
        int x = sales1.GetSize(), count = 1,k=0;
        if (x <= 10)
        {
            ar << x;
            for (int i = x - 1; i >=0; i--)
            {
                ar << sales1[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ar << 10;
            for (int i = x - 1; count != 10; i--)
            {
                ar << sales1[i];
                count++;
            }           
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        ar >> sizeOf10Records;
        lastUpTo10Sales.RemoveAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOf10Records; i++)
        {
            Sale* pNewSale;
            ar >> pNewSale;
            lastUpTo10Sales.Add(pNewSale);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `MainStore` and `Sale` classes properties :

```
class Sale :public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(Sale)
private:

    Customer* customer;
    Computer* computer;
    char* dateAndTime;

class MainStore:public CObject
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(MainStore)
private:
    Computer** computers;
    //list<Sale> sales;
    CTypedPtrArray<CObArray, Sale*> sales1;
    CTypedPtrArray<CObArray, Sale*> lastUpTo10Sales;
    int sizeOf10Records;
```

Both `Sale` and `Mainstore` are declared as serializable (Not sure about the latter if it is required) including the appropriate `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` in the respective classes and there is an empty constructor for `Sale` (as well as `MainStore`) that I tried to leave empty or tried to initialize the properties as `NULL` but still no luck.

I have been trying for days to get serializing working and it seems I am missing just a little detail but cannot figure what that is.

Any help with regards to why I am receiving `NULL` will be much appreciated and if there is any missing info in my post I will edit it accordingly.

Edit:

So my `Sale::Serialize` function was indeed empty but when reading back from the archive I get an error that says that `no operator ">>" matches these operands`

```
void Sale::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CObject::Serialize(ar);
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << computer;
        ar << customer;
        ar << dateAndTime;
    }
    else
    {
        ar >> computer;
        ar >> customer;
        ar >> dateAndTime;
    }
    
}
```

Edit 2:

Added Serialization to the `Customer` and `Computer` as well and edited
`ar>>dateAndTime` to `ar>> *dateAndTime`. Both the `char*` and and `Customer` classes no longer give me syntax error.
However `Computer` still does. `Computer` is an abstract class that inherits (as I read online on how to serialize abstract class) from `CObject` and has `void Serialize` function while the childs `DECLARE/IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` like so `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(ChildClass,Computer,1)` .

Comment: In the storing code you store objects (or array elements or structures) but in the loading code you read pointers. Also, the storing code could be further improved (store the last, up to 10 elements of the array - that check (if #items<10) could be changed. And you seem to reverse the items' order. And your data structures could be improved too, eg why have two separate arrays for sales and last 10 sales, it's hard to maintain and synchronize.

Comment: Aren't the elements in sales1 also pointers so I am also storing pointers to the objects and not objects themselves so the storing and loading are using the same thing. I am confused.

Comment: Have you tried to change `Sale* pNewSale` to `Sale* pNewSale = new Sale` and then Serialise? At the moment your element is a pointer to nothing so it is not possible to read it into anything.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? The entries of `lastUpTo10Sales` are not null, but the properties `customer`, `computer`, etc. are null? That would indicate an error in  `Sale::Serialize`; your `MainStore::Serialize` does not look wrong.

Comment: @j6t ```Sale::Serialize``` was indeed empty but when reading from the archive I get a syntax regarding the ```>>``` symbol. I have also added the ```Sale::Serialize``` code as well to the post. Do I need to add Serialize function to any member of the Sale class? But that does not explain why the ```char*``` member also gives me the same error.

Comment: Solved it! More info in the edit

Comment: @and MFC's deserializer constructs objects. You are not required to create an object the deserializer writes into. Instead, it uses the (static) class members provided by the `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro to construct instances of `CObject`-derived classes. If you `new` an instance yourself prior to deserializing, you are just creating a memory leak.

Comment: @IInspectable Gotcha.